# Upload the files from the client browser into mongodb or disk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, busboy

I am facing problem with uploading files using node.js and express framework.

Below is my app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

var app = express();

app.use(busboy());

app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    console.log(req.filename);
    req.pipe(req.busboy);   
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        });
    });
});
```

HTML code is

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fileupload" method="post">
    <div class="azureD" style="display:none;">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <label class="labelTemp">Subscription ID</label>
            <div class="clickRole addStoTabWid">
                <input type="text" id="" placeholder="" style="border:none;width:100%;">    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <label class="labelTemp">Upload .pem file</label>
            <div class="clickRole addStoTabWid">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="" style="border:none;width:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

I am getting the fallowing error in node.js console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at IncomingMessage.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:495:7)
at C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\app.js:138:9
at callbacks (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
at param (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
at pass (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
at Object.router (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:37:5)
at next (C:\Users\sangamesh.b\Desktop\release-2\Rapid_cloud\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
_stream_readable.js:505
dest.end();
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined
at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:505:9)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I have checked with everything i am not able fix this issue with my code please help me in this issue.

And i want to know any other alternative ways are there upload the file from the browser and store it into mongodb or localdisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following snippet. It works for you

```
var upload_path = path.resolve(__dirname + '../../../public/uploads');
var result = {
    status: 0,
    message: '',
    data: ''
};
fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {

    var imageName = Date.now() +"_"+req.files.file.name;

    /// If there's an error
    if(err){
        //error
    } else {
        var newPath = path.resolve(upload_path, imageName);

        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            if(err) {
               //error
            } else {
                fs.unlink(req.files.file.path, function() {
                    if (err) {
                        result.status = -1;
                        result.message = err;
                    } else {
                        result.data = imageName;
                    }
                    res.jsonp(result);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please can more elaborate it where i need to add this code snippet..Thanks in advance

Comment: And also after adding your code i am facing this issue ".write(string, encoding, offset, length) is deprecated. Use write(string[, offset[, length]][, encoding]) instead."

Comment: Replace this code with your after app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {

Comment: write(string[, offset[, length]][, encoding]). It happens due to express and node version. You have higher express version.

Comment: You are request to please mark my answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: @rapid Please mark answer as correct. thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: And one more help from your side after successful uploading of image i want to stay on that page only. how to do that? now its redirecting to some other thing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `fstream` is undefined as `file.pipe()` is causing the error. Make sure the `filepath` being passed into `fs.createWriteStream()` is correct.